# core dump only in production environment

Tags: unix, production-environment

i am recently migrating one project to use a new optimization library. Everything was tested fine in DEV server. However, when implemented in LIVE, some core dump occurs. By using dbx tool, it shows signal ILL and signal SEGV error, but hard to find the exact location of coredump.

I have compiled everything in DEV server and just deploy the executable to LIVE. Why is there such different behaviour in LIVE and DEV?

cannot find a similar question here so please help. below is the two examples of error. i have tried to trace at the indicated core dump location but no clue of why .

```
    **error 1:**
    core file header read successfully
    Reading ld.so.1
    Reading libcrypt_d.so.1
    Reading libnsl.so.1
    Reading libsocket.so.1
    Reading libgen.so.1
    Reading libkstat.so.1
    Reading libdl.so.1
    Reading libsched.so.1
    Reading libaio.so.1
    Reading librt.so.1
    Reading libm.so.2
    Reading libthread.so.1
    Reading libCrun.so.1
    Reading libc.so.1
    Reading libmd.so.1
    Reading libc_psr.so.1
    WARNING!!
    A loadobject was found with an unexpected checksum value.See help core mismatch for details, and run proc -map
    to see what checksum values were expected and found.
    dbx: warning: **Some symbolic information might be incorrect.
    t@1 (l@1) program terminated by signal ILL (illegal opcode)
    0xffffffffffffffff:     <bad address 0xffffffffffffffff>
    (dbx) exit**

    **error 2:**
    core file header read successfully
    Reading ld.so.1
    Reading libcrypt_d.so.1
    Reading libnsl.so.1
    Reading libsocket.so.1
    Reading libgen.so.1
    Reading libkstat.so.1
    Reading libdl.so.1
    Reading libsched.so.1
    Reading libaio.so.1
    Reading librt.so.1
    Reading libm.so.2
    Reading libthread.so.1
    Reading libCrun.so.1
    Reading libc.so.1
    Reading libmd.so.1
    Reading libc_psr.so.1
    WARNING!!
    A loadobject was found with an unexpected checksum value.
    See help core mismatch for details, and run proc -map
    to see what checksum values were expected and found.
    dbx: warning: **Some symbolic information might be incorrect.
    t@1 (l@1) program terminated by signal SEGV (no mapping at the fault address)
    0x03b2d8cc: seekoff+0x01c4:     ld       [%l4 + 32], %i3**
    Current function is 
    dbx: warning: can't find file "/opt/IMP/BUILD/CITOS_ENGINE_YPENG/src/make/automicro/../../include/entity/Voyage.hh"
    dbx: warning: see `help finding-files'
```